# Azure CLI publish python app function error Can't find app with name

Tags: python, azure-functions, azure-cli

Trying to publish a Python Azure function app to Azure and getting this error:

```
(.venv) PS C:\Users\jmatson\source\repos\funtionAppPythonGetInSiteTasks> func azure functionapp publish functionAppPythonGetInSiteTasks --remote
```

> Can't find app with name "functionAppPythonGetInSiteTasks"

```
Directory structure: 

    Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
    ----                -------------         ------ ----
    d-----        3/10/2019  11:06 AM                .venv
    d-----        3/10/2019  11:04 AM                .vscode
    d-----        3/10/2019  11:25 AM                functionAppPythonGetInSiteTasks
    -a----        3/10/2019  11:03 AM              2 .funcignore
    -a----        3/10/2019  11:03 AM            437 .gitignore
    -a----        3/10/2019  11:03 AM             27 host.json
    -a----        3/10/2019  11:21 AM            297 local.settings.json
    -a----        3/10/2019  12:44 PM            612 requirements.txt
```

Sub directory:

```
    Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
    ----                -------------         ------ ----
    d-----        3/10/2019  12:42 PM                __pycache__
    -a----        3/10/2019  11:04 AM            333 function.json
    -a----        3/10/2019  12:43 PM           1080 __init__.py
```

Empty function app exists in Azure:

[image]

Comment: you sure that function app exists? [you need to create it first](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-first-function-python#create-a-function-app-in-azure)

Comment: Yes, I created the function app via the CLI first, in the respective resource group etc. (Originally I hadn't, but then realised my mistake, created it, but this function still won't deploy)

Comment: I've updated original question with evidence.

Comment: May be another bug?  I see the command is trying to use —remote when I believe the syntax is `—build remote`

Comment: If you want to know how to publish python function, please refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-first-function-python#deploy-the-function-app-project-to-azure.

Comment: Thanks Jim. I'm fairly sure I've followed the documentation correctly and yet still had the above result (otherwise I wouldn't have posted here). I have since deleted this function entirely, re-tried and now it's working (using the same steps)

Comment: @JamesMatson If you have solved your issue, could you please post your answer? it may help more people.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I couldn't help but notice that the names of the function mentioned in your publish command and the one that exists on Azure mismatch (functionAppPythonGetInSiteTasks vs funtionAppPythonGetInSiteTasks). Could be a trivial observation, but try with the exact name?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you are giving the correct function app name. If you are not sure about your function app name then please run the below command to get the list of possible function apps that you can publish to.

> $az functionapp list --query "[].name"
>
> `Sample output:`
>
> `[`
>
>   `"azuswfntest123"`
>
> `]`

then run the actual command to publish the function app code.

> $func azure functionapp publish **azuswfntest123**

Answer (score 0):

I ended up 'solving' this, by removing the function app from Azure (via the UI) and then re-creating it, and re-uploading via the azure CLI. I'm unclear why this had the effect it did.

Comment: I couldn't help but notice that the names of the function mentioned in your publish command and the one that exists on Azure mismatch (functionAppPythonGetInSiteTasks vs funtionAppPythonGetInSiteTasks). Could be a trivial observation, but try with the exact name?

Comment: Oh dear, I think you've solved the issue! :/ Stupid, stupid me. Thanks!

Comment: No worries! Happens with the best of us. ;) I suggested the same as an answer below so it might help others who might run into the same issue and have a quick glance at this thread.

Answer (score 0):

FYI: I ran into this issue running a Python script to manage deployment of a Python Azure Function. I solved it by running `time.sleep(30)`, because it actually takes Azure a few seconds to bring the Function App to a state where you can publish to it. Very annoying bug.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and I solved it by adding service principal I am using to login to azure cli to role assignments of azure function as Contributor or Owner. So just a heads up, this might be an access issue that the user you logged in with does not have.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have multi tenant setup on your Azure, e.g. for development we use secondary tenant, so you have to login to that tenant.

> The following tenants require Multi-Factor Authentication (MFA). Use
> 'az login --tenant TENANT_ID' to explicitly login to a tenant.